# Can not delete \bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe - Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

I am facing a strange issue from roslyn compiler. Sometimes when I build the solution I face a strange issue in error list which does not let me build the solution. Here is the error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Unable to copy file "D:\Sealogical New Website\SealogicalWebsite\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\csc.exe" to "bin\roslyn\csc.exe". Access to the path 'bin\roslyn\csc.exe' is denied.  SealogicalWebsite
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Unable to copy file "D:\Sealogical New Website\SealogicalWebsite\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe" to "bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe". Access to the path 'bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe' is denied.   SealogicalWebsite

1. I try to clean the solution and rebuild it but does not work again.
2. Tried to delete files manually but again shows an error pointing out
   I do not have right permissions to do this:
3. Tried deleting from `CMD` but again shows the same error:

[image: Image when trying to delete files manually]

The only way to delete roslyn generated files is by restarting the PC and when restarted I can delete them manually without a problem.

I am administrator in my PC so there is no problem with that I guess.

This problem seems to happen in Visual Studi0 2015 and Visual Studio 2017.

I dont like restarting the PC 4-5 times a day or more thats why I am asking here.

Some other details:

- I am the one who created this project so theoretically it should not
  be a problem to do this action.
- When the project first created I did run the Visual Studion in
  Administrator Mode as I am doing now.
- I am using ASP.MVC 5 template in my project.
- Files which do not get deleted are `bin/roslyn/csc` and `bin/roslyn/VBCSCompiler`.

I could find a solution to remove this part from web.config so it does not generate those files:

```
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

But this solution would cause problem with new c# 6 features so I can not remove this section.....

Furthermore I tried this command in CMD to see if there is a process locking this file but anyway it did not show me any process at all:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tasklist /m D:\SealogicalNewWebsite\SealogicalWebsite\SealogicalWebsite\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
```

Does anybody knows a way how to handle this strange issue ?

Comment: There's probably a process running that has those files locked. Check the Task Manager to see if you can kill them. Also, unless you actually use VB, you can remove the `language="vb...` line

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I culd notice a process using VBCSCompiler which I ended as a task but again does not work. I tried to end some other tasks I could think about using those files but no success

Comment: What happens if you re-download the NuGet package? (maybe update it?)

Comment: I am not sure for that because I have not tried to re-download them and even if I try it will take some time from next occurrence but I think I will try it as an alternative

Comment: Since a recent update of VS 2017, me and my co-workers are getting this issue, too. The pragmatic solution in my case was to simply kill the sitll running process "VBCSCompiler" manually via Task Manager.

Comment: May be this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295103/3239305 will help you

Comment: See also related https://stackoverflow.com/q/44682281/292060, especially killing tasks without having to close VS.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Same problem here - solution for me was closing VS, open task manager and end all instances of VBCSCompiler.exe as mentionend here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71302/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build.html

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt but I will accept this as the best answer since I could not find any better answer than this one. Thanks :)

Comment: Per the link above on 09.27.2017 there is a fix slated for release in VS2017 V15.2.

Comment: VS 2019 latest version and still this answer solved my problem

Answer (score 11):

In the 'Manage NuGET Packages' window I downgraded Microsoft.Net.Compilers to 2.3.0 (from 2.3.1) and also downgraded Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform to 1.0.4 (from 1.0.5) and the Roslyn directory/files were no longer marked as readonly and no longer locked by the exe.

Comment: Just run `update-package` for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` in nuget console.

Answer (score 10):

Goto **Taskmanager** --> under process tab ---> find **VBCSCompiler.exe** and **end this task**. then try to delete the folder

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found this in Task Manager:

> Windows Explorer > (expand Windows Explorer) > Roslyn
>   Right-click Roslyn and select End Task

Note: Even closing all Windows Explorer windows will not stop Roslyn. You must do this in Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I killed the visual studio instance from Task manager then it got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have killed the process in task manager and rebuilt the solution which gets me back on track, but I have found that frequently building the entire solution before debugging has stopped it all together. I am currently working on an n-tier application and I was encountering this numerous times a day and I haven't had the issue since I made sure to build the application after any changes and especially before debugging. Though, I don't get why this would work since the VS builds the solution before debugging but it has done the trick for me.