# Why is Access to the path '/bin/roslyn' denied?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, msbuild-task

Long story short, I was able to build a bitbucket .NET/MVC/Angular project successfully on windows 2019 azure hosted agent, but I am unable to make it build successfully on ubuntu agent.
The reason I want to build it on ubuntu is because I noticed the build time is way faster than that of the windows agent, which makes sense considering the platforms.

I am facing this error:

```
Copying file from "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Bobby.ProjectA/obj/Debug/Bobby.ProjectA.pdb" to "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Bobby.ProjectA/bin/Bobby.ProjectA.pdb".
CopyRoslynCompilerFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Creating directory "/bin/roslyn".
  Creating directory "/bin/roslyn".
  Creating directory "/bin/roslyn".
  Creating directory "/bin/roslyn".

/home/vsts/work/1/s/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8/build/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(17,5): 
warning MSB3021: Unable to copy file "/home/vsts/work/1/s/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0/build/../tools/csc.exe" to "/bin/roslyn/csc.exe". Access to the path '/bin/roslyn' is denied. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Bobby.ProjectA/Bobby.ProjectA.csproj]
```

According to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71302/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=votes&type=problem) post, the issue is because the VBCSCompiler is locking the src.

So i have exhausted all of these solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65283319/8397835) to kill the VBCCompiler, but none of them worked.
I also can't restart the ubuntu agent during a build due to CI limitation, and `killall VBCSCompiler` bash script before msbuild task resulted in this error: `VBCSCompiler: no process found`

So now i am stumped, if VBCSCompiler process is not even running, why is `Access to the path '/bin/roslyn'` denied???

Ive also tried updating/installing `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` package per [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292947/8397835), but that didnt do/help anything.

This is how my build tasks looks like if it helps:

[image: build task]

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` do you use?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej not sure how to check that...would it be specified in the csproj file? I didnt write this project, I was just tasked with creating a build pipeline based on the project on bitbucket

Comment: It depends how you reference nugets. It could in csproj or in packages.config file. Please check this for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej thank you i found it in `packages.config` and the version is `1.0.8`.  `<package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net471" />`. Also since theyre kinda related, `<package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />`

Comment: Can you try update them to the newest version?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej i was gonna do that but then i realized there are numerous locations where this could be referenced, and i am not sure what all the locations (files) are

Comment: Run Ctrl+Shift to find accross all files. It pretty much should work on Visual Studio or Visual Code.